# Implement Java proxy server using RMI

Tags: java, proxy, rmi

We have working on simple definitions and concepts of Distributed Systems in computer networks which are
Replications and Transparency.
so I need to implement RMI client that connects to RMI proxy,then the proxy redirects the client connection to one of n-servers and choose to connect to one of these server based on some value between proxy and server.

so here we have n-servers replications and the client apply the transparency concepts that the client cannot connects directly to servers and from client perspective he can see only one server(proxy server).

Here is simple diagram for what i want to design using RMI only in java...
[image: Proxy and Replication Servers in JAVA]

So, as i have some experience in RMI i implement client and server using RMI
but here Does i need to implement the Proxy server as server to serve the client and as client for the n-servers or what .....????
how to put the first step in implementing proxy using RMI....

Answer (score 0):

Use RMI/IIOP with a load-balancing ORB.

Comment: i think , its complex details for my purpose, i want to do it in simple way like client server architecture but extra with proxy

Comment: There is nothing simple about implementing an RMI proxy, believe me. I've done it.